# why did beautifulsoup ignore a line of code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was learning how to use beautiful soup, where i realize in the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
    <html>
        <head><meta charset="UTF-8><title>something1</title><head>
        <body>             
            <p id= "p1">something2</p>
            <p id= "p2" class='red'>somthing3</p>            
        </body>
    </html>
'''

sp = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(sp.find('p'))
print(sp.find_all('p'))
print(sp.find('p',{'id':'p2', 'class':'red'}))
print(sp.find("p", id='p0'))
```

it will ignore p1 completely.

I then add a code on top of p1, p0

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
    <html>
        <head><meta charset="UTF-8><title>something1</title><head>
        <body>            
            <p id= "p0">something0</p>
            <p id= "p1">something2</p>
            <p id= "p2" class='red'>somthing3</p>            
        </body>
    </html>
'''

sp = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(sp.find('p'))
print(sp.find_all('p'))
print(sp.find('p',{'id':'p2', 'class':'red'}))
print(sp.find("p", id='p0'))
```

found out that it will just ignore the first line of code in body .

Why?

Comment: There's a typo in your html. You need to close the " in `charset="UTF-8` and then it should work.

Comment: Also, you don't correctly close the `<head>` section. So you should have `<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>something1</title></head>`

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your html. You need to close the `"` in `charset="UTF-8` and then it should work. So, you should have:

```html
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>something1</title></head>
```

which also correctly closes the `<head>` section tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken in two areas.

1. UTF-8 need to be enclosed in double-quotes
2. head tag isn't closed properly

<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>something1</title></head>